# Loading youtube video in my phonegap iphone app

Tags: iphone, cordova, youtube

Hi all im trying to load youtube/Dailymotion video using the iframe method in my phonegap  app on iphone but everytime i play the video the alert message popsup saying this movie could not be played please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried playing a non-commercial video, like a tutorial or something? If that plays you know at least that it is possible to play certain videos. There may be restrictions for playing some videos.

Comment: Well i tried playing a video using safaro from the simulator and it gave the same error "This movie cannot be played" so i think thats the issue with the simulator need help how to fix that